# Resolving and registering RequestContext in WebApi using StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, structuremap, fluentvalidation

I successfuly configured FluentValidator (FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider) in WebApi 2 to do validation when validator exist for web api method parameter.

Now I would like to implement validation in custom AbstractValidator class. I need there current user from HttpRequestContext or just IPrincipal resolved when validator is initilized.

App is using OWIN OAuthBearerAuthentication.

```
public class AddExamOptionRequest
{
}

    public class AddExamOptionValidator : AbstractValidator<AddExamOptionRequest>
        {
            private DbContext _db;

            public AddExamOptionValidator(DbContext db, IPrincipal currentUser)
            {
                // how to set up structure map to register IPrincipal or HttpRequestContext to be avilable here?
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested that but I believe this should work just fine:

```
x.For<IPrincipal>()
    .HttpContextScoped()
    .Use(c => c.GetInstance<HttpRequestMessage>().GetRequestContext().Principal);
```

Hope this helps!